# Create OAuth2PermissionGrant for Resources via Graph

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

My scenario is to create app & spn via AAD Graph. That ist rather easy (with a redirect for browser-based consent), what I now want to do is consent the spn right away (like you can do in the portal). The code itself is straight-forward:

```
var g = new OAuth2PermissionGrant();
g.ClientId = thePrincipal.ObjectId;
g.ConsentType = "AllPrincipals";
g.PrincipalId = null;
g.ResourceId = ##resourceId##;
g.ExpiryTime = DateTime.Now.AddYears(10);
g.Scope = "User.Read";
await client.Oauth2PermissionGrants.AddOAuth2PermissionGrantAsync(g);
```

Now the part that I haven't figured out properly is `##resourceId##`. This is supposed to be the `resourceId` - in the code sample, it should be Windows Azure Active Directory. How do I get the resourceId for eg the following required resource access (`00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000`):

```
RequiredResourceAccess =
    new [] {
        new RequiredResourceAccess() {
                ResourceAppId = "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
                    ResourceAccess = new [] {
                        new ResourceAccess() {
                            Id = new Guid("311a71cc-e848-46a1-bdf8-97ff7156d8e6"), // sign in and read profile (delegated perm)
                                Type = "Scope"
                        },
```

The lookup `ResourceAppId` -> `resourceId` (app to spn) is what I am missing. For eg AAD, Graph, manage.office.com et al.

Comment: Have you checked those two links? I'm not sure this implementation follows the guidelines.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-compare#scopes-not-resources
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-scopes

Comment: Just to clarify, are asking how you can find the App ID GUID for various Azure resource applications?

Comment: The AppId is easy to find (create app with permissions in portal, review the created application via Graph Explorer / Graph - that allows to find the AppIds). Problem is as stated going from the AppId to ResourceId as required by ServicePrincipal.

@baywet We are using the v1 endpoint (and no v2 is not an option because of its limitations)

Comment: The resource id should be the service principal object id for Azure AD Graph API etc. There is this endpoint that can get you the object id: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/functions-and-actions#servicePrincipalsByAppId

Comment: @juunas sounds promising. I also got (via a different channel) the comment to use https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/servicePrincipals?$filter=servicePrincipalNames/any(c:c eq 'https://manage.office.com') which might be similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation for the OAuth2PermissionGrant entity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#oauth2permissiongrant-entity), the *resourceId* field of an *OAuth2PermissionGrant* is the *objectId* of the *ServicePrincipal* object for the resource:

> Specifies the **objectId** of the resource service principal to which access has been granted.

So, from the tenant in which you are creating the *OAuth2PemrissionGrant*, you need to retrieve the *ServicePrincipal* object corresponding to the resource app you would like to grant permission to, and from that object, read the *objectId* property.

If you have the resource app's `AppId`, you can retrieve the corresponding `ServicePrincipal` object (if one exists) with:

```
GET https://graph.windows.net/{tenant}/servicePrincipals
        ?$filter=appId eq '{app-id-guid}'
        &api-version=1.6
```

With Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient (which I think is what you're using in your code), you would do this with:

```
graphClient.ServicePrincipals.Where(sp => sp.AppId == "{app-id-guid}")
```

If what you have to identify the resource app is not the Guid app ID, but a (somewhat) friendly identifier URI (e.g. "https://graph.microsoft.com"), you can retrieve the matching *ServicePrincipal* object by filtering on *servicePrincipalNames*.

With Azure AD Graph:

```
GET https://graph.windows.net/{tenant}/servicePrincipals
        ?$filter=servicePrincipalNames/any(n:n eq 'https://graph.microsoft.com'))
        &api-version=1.6
```

With Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient:

```
graphClient.ServicePrincipals
    .Where(sp => sp.ServicePrincipalNames.Any(n => n == "https://graph.microsoft.com"))
```